# MySQL Multiple word search regular expression

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm looking to create a regular expression to search a mysql column and I want order to matter.

```
select * from tapes 
where title like '%pod%' and title like '% b%' and title like '% si%' ;
```

This returns

```
"Pod Blind Sight"

"Pod Steve Blake"
```

I only want to return the first result. The purpose is when the user searches with "pod b s", to only return the top result. How do I write a regular expressoin to achieve that?

Comment: `WHERE title REGEXP 'pod.* b.* si'` or `'[[:<:]]pod.* b.* si'`

Comment: add that as an answer and ill give you the points!

Comment: Added as an answer with some explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `.*` (*zero or more occurrences of any char*) in between these values to match in this specific order:

```
WHERE title REGEXP 'pod.* b.* si'
```

Note you do not need to add `.*` at the start or end of the pattern as `REGEXP` finds *partial* matches.

Alternatively, if the `pod` must only be matched when at the beginning of a word, prepend the pattern with `[[:<:]]`:

```
 WHERE title REGEXP '[[:<:]]pod.* b.* si'
```

Keep in mind that MySQL REGEXP is case insensitive by default, add `BINARY` keyword to make it case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

This will achieve the problem *as currently stated*.

```
LIKE 'Pod% b% s%'
```

What do you want to happen with

```
"The Pod Blind Sight"
"Pod (Blind) Sight"
```

and many other possibilities?